# Adding Annotations to Heatmap in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I am having some trouble adding annotation bars on my hierarchical heatmap. I have a matrix with normalized values in df1. Such that:

**df1** <- Apple Bananas Oranges Kiwi Pear
5       7      5       3   8
6       2      4       5   9
5       9      3       5   2

I want to add an annotation bar that further segregates fruits into locations. This will then show us if we see random clustering by location.

I have another data frame called Annot:

**Annot**

Apple     North America
Bananas   Asia
Oranges   North America
Kiwi      Asia
Pear      North America

I want North America to be "Red" and Asia to be "Blue" in the colour bar.

I've tried the below code but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
 col = list(Annot = c("North America" = "red", "Asia" = "blue"))
 ha = HeatmapAnnotation(df = Annot, col=col)
 heatmap(df = df1, scale = "none", cexCol = 0.7, top_annotation = ha)
```

I get the following error

```
   Error in heatmap(df = df1, scale = "none", cexCol = 0.7, top_annotation = ha) : 
   argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

I've been trying this but getting a variety of errors.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking your dataframe specification for your question here. Include the full R code so that people can reproduce your example. At the moment there are lots of random numbers and words on a single line with no column headers etc. Put the whole reproducible example in a code block to make it as easy as possible for helpers.